# Preserve Data Type with Variant Direct Value Transfer

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to research how to preserve the data type using variants and direct value transfer. I have a column that has values such as

```
0001
A001
0B02
ZZZ1
```

I am transferring values from one table to another depending on the column name.

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim mc As Variant
Dim lc As Long 

x = raw_tbl.ListColumns(mc).DataBodyRange.Value
                .ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange = x
```

At the moment, if I copy the list above it loses the data formatting and turns into the following.

```
1
A001
0B02
ZZZ1
```

How can I preserve the data type of the column? I would like for it to be Text and not a number so the `0001` stays as `0001` and not the number `1`?

Comment: You'd need to set the NumberFormat of the destination range to Text before copying the values.

Comment: See also https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/table-number-formatting/

Comment: I import data from one worksheet into a table and there are 99 columns. I then transfer 96 of these columns into another table, but they are rearranged. The 96 column names are the same, so I use that to find the same column name and transfer (thanks to someone at Stackoverflow for helping with that solution!). There are varying data types in each of the columns. Some columns are numbers, some are text, and some are dates. Do I need to define all 96 columns before?

Comment: Instead of .Value you should use **.Text**: **x = raw_tbl.ListColumns(mc).DataBodyRange.Text**.

Comment: @VBasic2008 that did not work. My table was entirely empty.

Comment: The link I posted above talks about column formatting in list columns, but it's not so different from formatting on "regular" ranges.  In the various answers on your other question the essential operation is "copy from here to there", but the approaches vary between copy-paste (which also copies cell formats) and durect value assignment ( setting x.Value = y.Value) which does *not* copy formatting.  Seems you might want to use the copy/paste approach, or add an extra step to pre-format the destination range if you want to use the `Value` approach.

Comment: What @TimWilliams suggested is the right way to go.. try this `.ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"` and then `.ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange = x`

Comment: Awesome! It's getting closer. Thank you @SiddharthRout Rout. At the moment, it's converting everything to a text. The 96 column names will always be in the same order and have different types between columns, but each column will always have the same data type. I have columns that have text, some that have dates, and some that have numbers. It seems like pre-formatting destination range might be the solution? I am not sure what the most efficient way to do 96 columns would be. I appreciate all the assistance so far!

Comment: You can create Named Ranges of Columns and then preformat the ranges in one go before pasting the data

Comment: For example Col `A, C, M, Z` have number format. Then store these columns in a Named Range and then Simply do `Range("MyRange").NumberFormat = "0.00"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I did a test and added `ws_macro_imd.Range("tbl_imd[Para Num].NumberFormat ="@"` and it works on everything BUT the first row. When I initialize the workbook, I resize it so it is 1 row and clear the contents of the first row. `Set tbl_imd = ws_macro_imd.ListObjects("tbl_imd")
    With tbl_imd.DataBodyRange
        If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
        End If
    End With
tbl_raw.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents`

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: I did @SiddharthRout. I had to delete the first row of the table and then add a row since it was inheriting the data type of the first row. Now I just need to figure out how to make a Named Range of various columns in VBA without having to type 96 lines :) I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub CopyOverMatches()

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject
    Dim h As ListColumn, h2 As ListColumn, data

    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

    'loop over the headers from the source table
    For Each h In tbl1.ListColumns

        'is there a column of the same name in the destination table?
        Set h2 = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set h2 = tbl2.ListColumns(h.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not h2 Is Nothing Then '<< have a matching column

            data = h.DataBodyRange.Value

            With h2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), 1)
                .NumberFormat = h.DataBodyRange(1).NumberFormat
                .Value = data
            End With

        End If
    Next h

End Sub
```

Comment: This appears to work, but it does not preserve the data type still. Is `data` supposed to be a `Variant` also? Could this also be because when I initialize the workbook I resize the table to be 1 row and clear the contents of the first row as stated in a comment above?

Comment: It worked for me, with a destination table which had no rows.  It does depend on the formatting in the source columns being consistent, since it just picks up the format from the first row.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I got it to work by adding some code to delete the first row and then add a row before transferring the data over. I have various columns that have various data types, so I am just going to pre-define them I believe as stated in a solution above. Since some are numbers, some are text, and some are dates.

Comment: As long as your source table is correctly formatted, you shouldn't need to do anything else

Comment: Got it, I will have to try again tomorrow. I did not try your code by deleting the first row entirely in the destination table. That would be fantastic though. I appreciate it and I'll post back tomorrow!